# WatchGuard Mobile VPN with IPSec - "The VPN server did not respond"

Tags: vpn, ipsec

I have been following official WatchGuard guide (mvpn_ipsec_ios_vpn_c.html) to set up Mobile VPN with IPSec on WatchGuard Firebox x750e v10.2.12.

Inside the Policy manager, I can see this has been setup. The VPN group name is 'IPSecVPN'.

[image]
[image]

Then I configured the Mac client (Cisco IPSec) as instructed from URL above. I am still getting "The VPN server did not respond". I checked the traffic status on WatchGuard while I am making the VPN connection. I see no traffic origin from my IP address. It seems like I can't make connection to it. However, the same WatchGuard box with same external IP, I was able to make PPTP VPN to it.

Comment: First check the logs and see what messages your getting, do you have the log files going somewhere, can you post the output after a failed attempt?

Comment: For some reason, I can't see any IPSec logs on Watchguard box. Not even traffic denied from my IP. I can see other logs though, such as PPTP connections.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you save the config to the firebox using the admin (read/write) password.
I had a similar issue where I configured IPSec and tried to vpn immediately right after using an iphone and got the same error, once I saved the config to the firebox, I started getting different types of errors that I was able to eventually resolve by following carefully their IPSec vpn from iOS devices guide